# Start Activity from Soft Keyboard WITHOUT hiding the soft keyboard

Tags: android, android-activity, dialog, android-softkeyboard

I know this should not be a big challenge but it really drives me insane.

I am developing a simple soft keyboard input method and basically I have added a button to my softkeyboard, by pressing which, a dialog should pop up to prompt user to do some choices.

By far everything is ok about creating and opening the dialog. Since normally a dialog is created and displayed from outside an activity, so a flick solution could be to create a transparent activity which embedded the dialog in it. By doing so, I could easily start a dialog when user click the button on my softkeyboard.

But one tricky problem is: every time user click the button and the dialog (actually a dialog in a transparent activity) displays, it will always make my softkeyboard hide. I just need to start the dialog without any changes to the status of my softkeyboard -- I want my softkeyboard keeps showing when the dialog starts.

[image]

Here is a snapshot of Google Keyboard, it has the similar button which display a dialog and the dialog did not hide the keyboard, this is exactly what I want. So please anyone suggest me how to achieve this. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

THey aren't launching an Activity.  They're launching a dialog.  Which is tricky from an input method because its a service (you have to specify the dialog's window token to make it show) but doable.

Comment: Hello Gabe. But what I found actually was that Google Keyboard seems also embedded the dialog into a transparent activity coz when the dialog shows, the background edittext cursor would no longer flash, which seems to mean that there is a transparent activity on top of the actual screen.

Comment: I think you're reading too much into the cursor not moving.  I know the way I've successfully done dialogs in an IME is just to use a dialog and overwrite the dialogs window token to be the same token as my IME's UI.  Works perfectly.  I don't think there's any way to launch an activity and keep the keyboard up-  where would the input be going?

Comment: Could u pls tell me more about how to achieve this in detail.. I really got stuck here and I appreciate a lot about your help :)

Comment: Hi mate, I hv finally made it. It is indeed not a matter of activity, there is indeed a way to display a dialog directly from a service. Thx.

Comment: @jinnancun could you please share how you achieved it? I am in the same position, trying to show an AlertDialog from a SoftKeyboard.

Comment: @GabeSechan what do you mean by "overriding the dialog's window token"?